# Angular and lightgallery issue with src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular, lightgallery, lightgallery-2

I try to use lightGallery with an Angular 11+ application. The photo gallery works as expected when HTML content is created statically, i.e. `data-src` attribute of a tag inside lightGallery has static value:

```
<lightgallery [settings]="settings">
  <a data-lg-size="480-475-480, 800-791-800, 1406-1390" class="gallery-item"
    data-src="image1.jpg" data-responsive="image1-small.jpg" data-sub-html="Photo">
    <img class="img-responsive"
      src="image1-thumbnail.jpg" />
  </a>
</lightgallery>
```

However, following error message is displayed once `data-src` is set dynamically:

> Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

Not working part:

```
<lightgallery [settings]="settings">
  <a *ngFor="let image of images" data-lg-size="480-475-480, 800-791-800, 1406-1390" class="gallery-item"
    data-src="{{image.src}}" data-responsive="{{image.responsive}}" data-sub-html="Photo">
    <img class="img-responsive"
      src="{{image.thumbnail}}" />
  </a>
</lightgallery>
```

Example is here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lightgallery-angular-z5vdhv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

What I do wrong here?

Comment: You need to use attr for that. So [attr.data-src]=“image.src”.. same for data-responsive

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you should import LightgalleryModule in your component :

```
imports: [LightgalleryModule, CommonModule],
```